# Query a stored procedure for it's parameter names and types

Tags: .net, sql, oracle, plsql, odp.net

Is there any easy way to query a stored procedure (Oracle - PL/SQL) for what parameters it expects?

I know that I can query `USER_SOURCE` to get the whole procedure but I'd then have to parse the whole procedure, and if the parameter is of type `[table].[column]%TYPE` I'd then have to query the table schema as well.

Either using just sql or via ODP.Net.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting ORACLE programming object definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771458/getting-oracle-programming-object-definitions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The USER_ARGUMENTS view will give you the details.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to call [DBMS_DESCRIBE.DESCRIBE_PROCEDURE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_descrb.htm#BAJDBCIE).