# Find the parameter names of a stored procedure

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I have a stored procedure. Is there a simple query I can execute that will give me the parameter names?

I have found this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062623/query-a-stored-procedure-for-its-parameter-names-and-types) but it is not for Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get names only you can use this query:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.parameters
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourProcedureName')
```

To get more detailed info (name, type and length of parameter):

```
SELECT p.name AS ParameterName, t.name AS ParameterType, p.max_length AS ParameterLength
FROM sys.parameters AS p
JOIN sys.types AS t ON t.user_type_id = p.user_type_id
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourProcedureName')
```

Comment: `WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourProcedureName')`

Comment: I am having some issues with this. I changed it to say `SELECT * FROM sys.parameters;` but it returns 0 rows. Any ideas?

Comment: @user489041 - If you are selecting every record from sys.parameters and your record count is 0, that would lead me to believe you don't have any stored procedures with parameters created *in the database* where you're executing that query.

Comment: right - you need at least one custom stored procedure with parameters to have entries in this table

Answer (score 2):

On top of what Marek stated, you can also retrieve them programatically using the DeriveParameters method in the .NET library:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check out my blog on database files and objects.  http://craftydba.com/?p=2901

I have a stored procedure called SP_STORE_PRIMES in my sample [MATH] database.

One way is to use the sys.parameters table.  This can be optionally joined to types.  Below is joined to sys.objects.

```
-- Parameters to SP & FN
select o.name, p.* from sys.parameters p join sys.objects o
on p.object_id = o.object_id where is_ms_shipped = 0
go
```

[image]

A older system stored procedure is sp_sproc_columns.

```
-- Older system stored proc - show all parameters to one
sp_sproc_columns @procedure_name = 'SP_STORE_PRIMES'
go
```

Both ways will get you where you want to go.

[image]