# Count number of parameters passed to a procedure in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a procedure in which I have allowed variable number of arguments i.e

```
CREATE Procedure OutputProcedure
 @FirstName nvarchar(20) = null,
 @MiddleName nvarchar(20) = null, 
 @LastName nvarchar(20) = null, 
 @City nvarchar(20) = null,
 @AveragePercentage int out

AS
BEGIN
/*CODE*/
End
```

Now, I want to be able to count the number of arguments which were passed to the procedure inside of this procedure itself. How can I do this?

I found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431523/query-to-find-number-of-parameters-in-a-stored-procedure-or-function-in-sql-serv) but it takes the name of the procedure being checked for the arguments which I think should not be the case if I was to do count inside of the same procedure only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this inside the `SP`. Try this.

```
Declare @cnt int

select @cnt = case when @FirstName is not null then 1 else 0 End+
       case when @MiddleName is not null then 1 else 0 End+
       case when @LastName is not null then 1 else 0 End+
       case when @City is not null then 1 else 0 End 

Select @cnt
```

Comment: So, Param_Count then should store the value,right? I try to select the value and SSMS does not see it .Where am I wrong?

Comment: @sim - If you want to store the count then `delcare` a variable and store the count in that variable. Updated check now