# Is it possible to pass multiple parameters to a stored procedure without knowing how many parameters the stored procedure requires?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I'm currently using a stored procedure to look up the name of a stored procedure based on a primary key in my database. I execute this initial stored procedure using LINQ to SQL. Once I have the stored procedure name I'm then using the following code to execute the stored procedure.

```
DbContext.ExecuteQuery(returnType, retrievedStoredProcedureName, new object[] {parameters});
```

The problem that I have now is that I do not know what parameters are required and what the data type is. Is there anyway to accomplish this without using `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters()`?

Comment: Can't you just return the parameter information from the first procedure? How will you know what to put in those parameters?

Comment: Yeah I could return the parameter information from the first procedure. Wouldn't I still need a way to determine what the type of the parameters are though?

Comment: Did you see this question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431523/query-to-find-number-of-parameters-in-a-stored-procedure-or-function-in-sql-serv

Comment: @LoekD That does help some, thanks for the suggestion.