# Oracle Stored Procedure's Input Arguments

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, arguments

I know I can use the SQL below to query a list of stored procedures in Oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_PROCEDURES
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME
```

But how can I retrieve a list of arguments I needed to pass in for a particular stored proc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting ORACLE programming object definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771458/getting-oracle-programming-object-definitions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system view `all_arguments` will give you this information, but bear in mind that it will yield no rows if the procedure in question has no parameters:

```
SELECT argument_name, data_type, in_out, position
FROM all_arguments
WHERE object_name = 'MY_PROC'
AND owner = USER
AND data_level = 0
ORDER BY position;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the [following](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm) Oracle documentation to be helpful. I believe the command you are looking for is,

```
  DESCRIBE procedure
```